# UI scaling issue for iPhone 4-inch and 4.7-inch

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm designing my UI using the iPhone 4-inch size on the View Controller Simulated Metrics. I also used auto layout and it looks perfect on iPhone 5 and 5s simulator. However, when i open another Main.storyboard(Preview) for iPhone 4.7-inch, it appears that it did not scale to the whole 4.7 inch view. how do i go about doing this? should i pick iPhone 4.7-inch when designing my UI? but i think that will mess up the smaller 4-inch preview. please help, i want the iPhone 4.7-inch preview looks exactly the same as iPhone 4-inch preview, with no excess space. is that even possible to begin with? there seems to be no answers online about this.

Answer (score -1):

Whether or not 4 inch views in storyboard will scale up or stretch to 4.7 or 5.5 inch screens is determined by your launch image. Set your launch image with dimension 640 x 1136, then everything from 4 inch screen will be stretched to 4.7 or 5.5 inch screens of iPhone 6 or higher!

Comment: Why would some one down vote this? Remember to comment when you down vote because I'm 100% sure this is this how I solved this problem